# Monitor application process for each client

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out if I can manage my installed program through checking if its running or not. So right now I currently using this script as my basis to monitor my local application.

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import time

while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        if 'Python_Script.exe' not in subprocess.Popen('tasklist', stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]:                
                print 'Application was closed'
```

Note: this is my local application and my aim is to check the status for each clients e.g. (192.168.21.2, 192.168.21.3, 192.168.21.4, 192.168.21.5),

Comment: So what is your question? doesn't this code work?

Comment: This code is working, and my point is it was only local (My Computer), and my aim is to make it through network. Just like a simple pinging through network but this time I need to check if my application is running for each clients

Comment: First, you must run this program on other computers. Then, if you want send the output to your computer, you should use [socket](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html).

Comment: I got the idea, but could you give an example so that I can have an idea how will I start it

Comment: Yes, please wait me a minute.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should write a program that can send the output to your computer.

I recommend [socket](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html). Here is a simple program that can send some text to the server:

```
from socket import *

def server():
    try:
        s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
        port = int(input('Enter the port: '))

        s.bind(('', port))

        while True:
            print('\nWaiting for a massage...')
            msg = s.recvfrom(1024)
            print(msg)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        f.close
        print('\n\nServer exit.')


def client():
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)

    host = str(input('\nEnter the server\'s IP: '))
    port = int(input('Enter the port: '))

    s.sendto("Here is the text that you'd like send to the server")\
    .encode('UTF-8'), (host, port))

    print('\nThe massage has been send.')
```

1. This is a Python 3 program. Maybe you should convert it to Python 2.
2. You can write your program as a function, and `return 'Application was closed'` then send it.

However this is just an example, you need write the full program yourself. Good luck :)